# RXJava how to try to get next after x time

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I wan to do a call to a web service using retrofit every x seconds until y condition is raised.

I want to run `OrderApi.get` after x seconds until the response is null.

```
public class OrderApi {}
    public static Observable<Order> get() { 
        //...
    }
}


OrderApi.get(order.getId()))
        .subscribe(updatedOrder -> {
          mShouldRun = updatedOrder != null;
        });
```

Already saw operators like `Observable.delay` `Observable.timber` but I cant find a way to use them properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work

```
 Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<?> call(Long aLong) {
                        return OrderApi.get();
                    }
                }).takeUntil(new Func1<Object, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Object o) {
                return o==null;
            }
        }).subscribe(observer);
```

Comment: I select this answer because `Observable.interval` emits objects forever until `takeUntil` is false. `Observable.timer` just wait x time to emit one object.

Answer (score 1):

a combination of `timer` and `repeat` should do it

```
Observable.timer(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .repeat(Schedulers.io())
       .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
           @Override
           public void call(Object aLong) {
              System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
           }
       });
```

the callback `call` is called every 1 sec

Comment: and when to stop? how can I check the property and make the observable stop?

Comment: `subscribe` returns a `Subscription` option. Old a reference and call  `unsubscribe()` when you want to stop it

Comment: I select this answer because `Observable.interval` emits objects forever until takeUntil is false. `Observable.timer` just wait x time to emit one object.