# How to call a method after a delay in android using rxjava?

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm trying to replace my Handler method with RxJava.
My requirement:

> I want to call the method getTransactionDetails() only after 5
>   seconds.

This my working code using Handler:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        getTransactionDetails();
      }
    }, 5000);
```

Rx java code - it's not working:

```
Observable.empty().delay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnNext(o -> getTransactionDetails())
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288546/rxjava-how-to-try-to-get-next-after-x-time this might help

Comment: use delaySubscription method for RxJava2: .delaySubscription(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[`doOnNext()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#doOnNext-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-) is for side effects. It could be use for example for logging purpose, because logging doesn't alter the flow of data. But you want to pass down the result of `getTransactionDetails()`, so you should use map instead.

Second, [`Observable.empty()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#empty--) create an `Observable` that just propagate the finish/dispose message, it trigger neither `doOnNext()` neither `map()`. You could fix this using [`Observable.just()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#just-T-) instead but a more idiomatic way would be to use [`Observable.timer()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#timer-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-):

```
Observable.timer(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .map(o -> getTransactionDetails())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe( ... );
```

A final note on Schedulers. `Observable.timer()` and `delay()` are executed on the computation scheduler by default so you don't need to call `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to execute `getTransactionDetails()` outside of main thread. `Observable.timer()` and `delay()` could take a `Scheduler` as a parameter if you want to control this. So you need to call `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` if you want to use `getTransactionDetails()` result on UI thread. Every operator after `observeOn()` is executed on the defined `Scheduler`, so you have to put `observeOn()` after computation.

**Edit**: This is of course if you care about the result of `getTransactionDetails()`. If not, see Clyde answer.

Comment: The map should probably be before the observeOn That way it is run on the RxComputation thread rather than the main thread.

Comment: @GeoffreyMarizy how can i call this daily on 12:00 am?

Comment: As for I know, RxJava dosn't support this use-case. Which make sense, since Rx is no more than a (supercharged) observer pattern.

Comment: what really helped me understand me my problem was the part about schedulers; upvoted.

Answer (score 91):

This is how I would do it:

```
    Completable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(this::getTransactionDetails);
```

A [Completable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html) represents a deferred computation with no value but an indication for completion or exception. The static method call [`timer()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#timer-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-io.reactivex.Scheduler-) returns a `Completable` that signals completion after the specified time period has elapsed, and the `subscribe()` call will mean that the method `getTransactionDetails()` will be called on the current object when the timer fires. By supplying a `Scheduler` as the last argument to `Completable.timer()` you control which thread is used to execute `getTransactionDetails()`.

Answer (score 13):

```
Observable
     .timer( 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS )
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .map(o -> getTransactionDetails() )
     .subscribe();
```

you dont need observeOn because subscribe empty.
use timer it will be more correct way

Comment: Why do you execute the function in `.map` and not in `.subscribe()`?

Answer (score 11):

It's not working, because `delay()` needs something to be emitted, but `empty()` actually emits nothing.

Instead, you should use `Observable.timer()`.

Comment: Alternatively `Completable.complete().delay(...)`

Answer (score 7):

Delay subscription already [defined](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/delaySubscription.s.png). Your example can be implemented in this way:

```
getTransactionDetails().delaySubscription(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Observable.just(true).delay(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .map(o -> getTransactionDetails())
    .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a disposable that can be used with the view then use a Completable 
Completable returns an Object which terminates as soon as one of the source Completables terminates (normally or with an error) and cancels all other Completables.

Eg :

```
Completable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(() -> {
                // code after delay here
            });
```

If you want for a service to get complete i would recommend a Subscription

Eg :

```
observable.timer(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .map(o -> {
              // your code after delay here
              })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe( ()-<{
                   // enter the service here
                } );
```